# What is $\text{Cov}(X/Y, Y)$?

Tags: covariance, ratio

I've been searching the answer to my question (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/476156/how-to-estimate-the-correlation-between-ratio-and-ratios-denominator) and think that it might be formulated like this as well. Is there an answer?

Greatful for any help!

Comment: Do you know the definition of covariance in terms of expected values?

Comment: No, I don't, could you please rephrase the question, because, sorry, I can't get what you're asking!

Comment: I mean is there any way to remake this Cov(X/Y, Y) to some equation with Cov(X) and cov(Y) ?

Answer (score 2):

For any two random variables $Z,W$, we have
$$\operatorname{Cov}(Z,W)=\operatorname{E}[ZW]-\operatorname{E}[Z]\operatorname{E}[W].$$

Therefore,

$$\operatorname{Cov}\left({\frac{X}{Y},Y}\right)=\operatorname{E}[X]-\operatorname{E}[X/Y]E[Y]$$